# number string NaN error correction workaround

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a member variable `total` explicitely of type `number` (in a `strict` Angular app) which is initialized in the `constructor` but then shows as type `any` in the `drawSlices()` method, resulting in my tooltip label showing `NaN`.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
         
  total: number;
  dataSource: Item[];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataSource = this.dataService.getData();
    this.total = this.dataSource.reduce((sum, element) => sum += element.abs, 0);
  }
    
  drawSlices() {   
    const mousemove = function (event, d) {
      const percent = (Math.abs(d.data.abs / this.total) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
      tooltip
        .style("left", (event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (event.pageY - 80) + "px")
        .style("display", "block")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("height", "40px");
      tooltip.html(`name: ${d.data.name}<br>value: ${d.data.value}<br>share: ${percent}`);
    }
}
```

I have tried forcing the type, and similar workarounds, to no avail...

```
let t: number = this.total;
const percent = (Math.abs(d.data.abs / t) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
```

How do I fix this to get a number followed by `%`?

Comment: Just as a heads-up: Specifying / casting a variable to a specific type in *typescript* will NOT change how the data is stored in the variable. You can still mess it up and as example have a string being stored in a variable of type `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the scope of 'this' in mousemove function.
Convert the normal function to an ES6 (arrow) function and you should be good to go. It will get the scope of the component, and would return the correct 'total' variable.

```
const mousemove = (event, d) => {
  const percent = (Math.abs(d.data.abs / this.total) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
  ...
}
```

Put a debug point for the line you are using this.total and see the value assinged to it.